# Directory access outside of wwwroot for a WCF service hosted on IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-7

I've been working on a WCF service that is currently hosted on IIS. I need to get the WCF service to access a directory outside of the wwwroot folder.

Am I right in assuming that directory access outside of wwwroot is restricted to WCF apps hosted on IIS as it would be restricted for an ASP.Net application hosted on IIS?

If this is the case, what is the safest way of allowing the WCF service to acccess a set folder outside of the wwwroot?

BTW - I'm running in Mixed Transports Mode, not ASP.Net compatibility mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File access is going to be limited based on the identify of the application pool that is hosting your service.  Your service will be able to access any file the application pool identity has access to whether it is in the root of your IIS website or not.  If you want to access files within the root of your website using relative paths with something like Server.MapPath then you'll have to run your WCF service in ASP.Net compatability mode.  See the following page for details on WCF with ASP.Net compatability mode:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best approach is to create another application pool for your service and assign a specially created account as the identity of your new application pool. Then give the needed permissions of the account to the folders and file you need to access. You can make the external folder a virtual directory of the site if you want to reference it with a relative path.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Pencho. I think I'd have to be running though WCF service in ASP.Net compatibility mode to use the virtual directories, wouldn't I? I'm currently running it in Mixed Transports Mode.

Comment: Yes, to use virtual directories and relative pathing you'll have to run in ASP.Net Compatability Mode.